# Find all the numbers $n$ such that $3\cdot 2^n+2\cdot 3^n\equiv 1 \pmod 7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find all the numbers $n$ such that $3\cdot 2^n+2\cdot 3^n\equiv 1 \pmod 7$

*Attempt:*

$\star$ denotes $3\cdot 2^n+2\cdot 3^n$

$$\text{for  }n=1:\quad\star\equiv 5\not\equiv 1\\
\text{for  }n=2:\quad\star\equiv 5\not\equiv 1\\
\text{for  }n=3:\quad\star\equiv 3\not\equiv 1\\
\text{for  }n=4:\quad\star\equiv 0\not\equiv 1\\
\text{for  }n=5:\quad\star\equiv \color{red}1\\
\text{for  }n=6:\quad\star\equiv 5\not\equiv 1\\
\vdots$$

this is how should I aprroach this? or maybe there is smarter way?

Comment: Well, since $(7,a)=1\implies a^6\equiv 1 \pmod 7$ your calculation shows that you just want $n\equiv 5\pmod 6$.

Comment: lulu's comment is probably the best one can say here, but just to highlight another approach: $2\equiv3^2\pmod7$, and so you are trying to solve $3\cdot3^{2n}+2\cdot3^n\equiv1\pmod7$, which means that $3^n$ must be a root, modulo $7$, of the quadratic polynomial $3x^2+2x-1=(3x-1)(x+1)$. Thus we need $3^n\equiv3^{-1}\equiv5\pmod7$ or $3^n\equiv-1\equiv6\pmod7$, which means that $n\equiv5\pmod6$ or $n\equiv3\pmod6$. We discover that your calculation for $n=3$ was incorrect, missing a second solution.

Comment: Your calculations are incorrect for $\,n =2\,$ and $\,n = 3\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea. Working mod $7,\,$ by little Fermat $\,2^6\equiv 1\equiv 3^6\pmod 7\,$ so the sequence $\,f_n \equiv 3\cdot 2^n + 2\cdot 3^n \,$  has period $\,6,\,$ i.e $\, f_{n+6}\equiv f_n.\,$ So we need only check the first cycle for $\,n = 0,\ldots, 5.\,$ Using $\,2^3\equiv 1,\ 3^3\equiv -1\,$ we compute the cycle as

$$\begin{eqnarray} 3\ (1&,&2&,&4&,&\ \ \,1&,&\,\ \ 2&,&\,\ \ 4)\\
+\ 2\ (1&,&3&,&9&,&{-}1&,&{-}3&,&{-}9)\\
\equiv \ \  (5&,& 5&,& 2&,&\,\ \ \color{#c00}1&,&\,\ \ 0 &,&\,\ \ \color{#0a0}1)\end{eqnarray}$$

Therefore, we conclude that $\ f_n \equiv 1\iff $  $\,\color{#c00}{n\equiv 3}\ $ or $\,\ \color{#0a0}{n \equiv  5}\, \pmod 6$

Answer (score 1):

As $2^3\equiv1,3^3\equiv-1\pmod7$

let us start with $n=3a,3a+1,3a+2$

**Case**$\#1:$  $n=3a$
$$1\equiv3\cdot2^{3a}+2\cdot3^{3a}\equiv3+2(-1)^a$$

$\iff2(-1)^a\equiv-2\iff(-1)^a\equiv-1$ as $(2,7)=1$

$\implies a$ is odd $=2b+1$(say) $\implies n\equiv3\pmod6$

**Case**$\#2:$ $n=3a+1$

$$1=3\cdot2^{3a+1}+2\cdot3^{3a+1}\equiv6(1+(-1)^a)$$

$\iff1+(-1)^a\equiv6^{-1}\equiv6$ as $6^2\equiv1\pmod7$

$\iff(-1)^a\equiv5\pmod7$ which is impossible as $5\not\equiv\pm1\pmod7$

**Case**$\#3:$ $n=3a+2$

Left for you!